# Are there any SharePoint virtual machines available from Microsoft?

Tags: virtual-machine

I am just starting with SharePoint and have read in various articles that there **was** an official SharePoint 2010 virtual machine available from Microsoft. This [answer on SharePoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/34796/20540) points to this link:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

But the link is now dead. I was able to find other third party virtual machines like the one mentioned in this [blog article](http://gauravmahajan.net/2013/01/06/sharepoint-2013-rtm-on-win-server-2012-virtual-machine-download/), but none from Microsoft.

Are there any SharePoint virtual machines available from Microsoft? Are there any other sites on which the SharePoint 2010 VM, or for that matter any version, from Microsoft is still available? Has Microsoft discontinued providing VMs for SharePoint?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SP.SE, Naveen. To the best of my knowledge, Microsoft doesn't supply virtual maschines for SharePoint development purposes. But there are useful guides, such as [Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/office/ee554869(v=office.14).aspx). Feel free to ask more questions on setting up the development environment. Nice to see you here!

Comment: @BennySkogberg: I had seen this link earlier but I am using Windows 8.1. Any ideas if SharePoint is compatible with Windows 8.1?

Comment: If you have Windows 8.x you can enable Hyper-V in the Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features by clicking "Turn Windows features on or off". When Hyper-V is enabled, start by installing Windows Server, SQL Server and last SharePoint. Preferably by using [AutoSPInstaller]( https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.

Comment: Naveen, how much RAM you have on this Win8.1 system?  If you have 8GB+ RAM, then I would recommend to setup Evaluation Versions of Products inside Hyper-V VM. (Assuming that yours is Win 8.1 Pro 64-bit)

Comment: @kamleshrao: I have 8GB RAM, 64-bit but **not** Windows 8.1 Pro. Its the low cost version Windows 8.1 Single Language. Don't know if Hyper-V would be available to me.

Comment: @Naveen - it needs **Windows 8** Pro or **Windows 8 Enterprise** (Check the Hardware Requirements for Hyper-V section in this blog post  - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/olivnie/archive/2013/01/18/hyper-v-on-client-windows-8-pro.aspx)

Comment: @kamleshrao: So a third party VM like VMWare or Virtual Box is my only option?

Comment: That's right. VirtualBox is free option and works well.  VMWare is paid one, but powerful.

Comment: @Naveen please check out my answer, it gives the link that your refering too but also gives another solution to build it yourself if you wnated to.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunatly there is no vm for 2010 available since 2013 came out! you need to build it yourself!

you need a few things:

1) a virtual machine like Oracle VM VirtualBox (I use and is reliable)

2) a windows server (for you windows 8x)

3) sharepoint 2010 installation!

4) sql server installation (depending on your structure)

you can follow this guide to install sharepoint 2010 on win 8 server:

[Installing Sharepoint Development Environment on Windows 8 Professional Edition?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51365/installing-sharepoint-development-environment-on-windows-8-professional-edition)

or

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/01/27/sharepoint-2010-virtual-machine-for-customers-partners-now-available.aspx

or you can use some other site that has the vm other than microsoft website like:

**2010 Information Worker Demonstration Virtual Machine (Beta)**

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Internet/Servers/Server-Tools/Information-Worker.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a dev environment in azure.

[Step by step tutorial](http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/01/07/step-by-step-build-a-free-sharepoint-2013-lab-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-31-days-of-servers-in-the-cloud-part-7-of-31.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Checkout www.cloudshare.com they have some prebuilt sharepoint 2010 development virtual machines.

Comment: Thanks. I already have created an account there. I am looking for a solution with VM so that I can run it on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually find a working install for Sharepoint 2013 on vmware at this address:

[SharePoint Server 2013 SP1 Virtual Machine Download](http://gauravmahajan.net/2014/08/17/sharepoint-server-2013-sp1-virtual-machine-download/)

and also here:

[SharePoint 2013 Evaluation VHD.](http://thuansoldier.net/?p=3428)

This is interesting because it is provided with or without demo data and also include Lync, Exchange and so on.