# Where can download a SharePoint 2010 VM

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, download

From where I can download SP 2010 Virtual Machine?

Will it run smoothly in my system? My system config is:

- 4 GB RAM
- 2.24 GHz Processor
- Windows 7.

Answer (score 4):

There were some SharePoint 2010 evaluation VM's available from Microsoft at one point but I don't think you can get them anymore. Even if you could, they can only be used for a limited time - generally between 30 and 90 days.

You can create your own VM for SharePoint 2010 quite easily. If you use SharePoint Foundation instead of SharePoint Server you can get away with assigning 2GB RAM to the VM which would leave you 2GB for the host OS.

[Setting Up the Development Environment for SharePoint 2010 on Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

i have no idea what you mean by:

> From where I can download SP 2010 VM in my system

where to install in your vm or where to download a vm to install on your local machine?

it will run on your setup but will not be smooth, i think you should be looking at atleast 6gb ram.... your going to be running sql server on the same vm if its a tests vm amoungst other things that will hog system resources!!

about test vms for download!

[Are there any SharePoint virtual machines available from Microsoft?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/are-there-any-sharepoint-virtual-machines-available-from-microsoft)

for hardware requirments:

> Processor  64-bit, four cores   RAM
>
> •4 GB for developer or evaluation
> use
>
> •8 GB for production use in a single server or multiple server farm
> Hard disk  80 GB for system drive
>
> You must have sufficient space for the base installation and
> sufficient space for diagnostics such as logging, debugging, creating
> memory dumps, and so on. For production use, you also need additional
> free disk space for day-to-day operations. Maintain twice as much free
> space as you have RAM for production environments. For more
> information, see Capacity management and sizing for SharePoint Server
> 2010.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(office.14).aspx

Answer (score 3):

As previously stated, you should have at least 6GB of RAM to run an SP2010 VM, but you'd be better off with 8 or more.

The pre-built VM's for 2010 by Microsoft are getting harder to find, IMHO. I always use this guide as my go-to because it gets you up and running with a good, stable, all-in environment with links to all of the evaluation software.

http://www.criticalpathtraining.com/articles/sharepoint-server-2010-rtm-virtual-machine-setup-guide-v1-8/

I don't work for the company, or represent them in any way. I just get a LOT of use out of this guide, and hope other people find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have MSDN subscription it is worth creating your VMs up in the cloud :)

You can activate the [Windows Azure Benefit for MSDN Subscribers](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/member-offers/msdn-benefits-details/) and spin up VMs in few minutes.

P.S. Remember, you can install SharePoint 2010 on client OS like windows 7 but you can't do the same for SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score -1):

Your configuration is not sufficient to run a VM for SharePoint 2010 smoothly. There should have minimum 8 GB RAM for your system. Instead what you can do is, install SharePoint stand alone directly in your Windows 7 environment.

Comment: That does not really help to increase his low amount of RAM though?